# compare class of path elements to a dataset

Tags: d3.js, datamaps

I am really new to d3 and I want to make a choropleth map with the d3 datamaps so if have to compare the classes of the pathways to my dataset. So far I did manage to get the path's

html

```
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"</script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/d3map/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
  <div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
  <script src="d3map.js"></script>
```

js code

```
var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('container'),
  })
  var country = d3.selectAll("path")
```

Country is an array containing 177 elements
one element in country has this form:

```
<path d="bunch of numbers" class="datamaps-subunit AFG" style="etc"></path>
```

i want to see if the country code in the class (e.g. AFG) matches one in my dataset.

Country.class gives undefined

I am probably missing something really obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2v5sgmz/

You can filter specific classed elements in an array with the `filter` method like this:

```
var country = d3.selectAll("path");

var afg = country.filter(function(d,i){
   if( d3.select(this).classed("AFG") ){
        return d3.select(this);
   }
})
```